# Can I configure directory listings and MIME type mappings from command line?

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3

I want to publish a directory of static files alongside my application on GlassFish 3.1; in order to do that, I have to enable directory listings and add a custom MIME type mapping. Since this will only be needed in some installations, I want to do the configuration on the server instead of putting it in the application.

Both can be achieved by editing the **default-web.xml** file in the domain configuration.

To enable directory listings I have to change the `listings` parameter to `true` inside the `servlet` block:

```xml
<servlet>
  <!-- more stuff -->
  <init-param>
    <param-name>listings</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <!-- more stuff -->
</servlet>
```

To add a MIME type mapping I have to add a block like this one:

```xml
<mime-mapping>
  <extension>ext</extension>
  <mime-type>text/plain</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

I'd like to do this from a script so that I can reproduce the installation as needed.

Is there a way to change these configurations using `asadmin` or some other command line tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asadmin does not provide element level access to default-web.xml.  That said, you may just want to have an alternate copy of default-web.xml and then use a script to replace the 'shipped' version with the customized version.

Comment: Thanks. I will probably upload a diff and patch the shipped file (though diffing XML files is not beautiful).

Comment: IMHO, changing `<server_name>.http-service.virtual-server.server.property.default-web-xml` property to point to a custom file would be a better idea than replacing the default master file.